# Deny file input camera shot feature

Tags: jquery, html

I have HTML submit form (only part of it below):

```
<label for="file-upload">
    <div class="button">Choose</div>
</label>
<input id="file-upload" type="file" name="file-upload" />
```

Code is working fine on Desktop and Mobile. What I need to do is to disable possibility of "Camera snap" feature on Mobile version, it would be perfect if only file manager would appear on "Choose file" button. ( screenshot: http://prntscr.com/csm6ji )

Has anyone done something similar to this and could help me out? :)

Comment: Did you solve it?

Comment: @RonyTesler no.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the accepts attributes:

[see here](https://dev.opera.com/articles/media-capture-in-mobile-browsers/)

e.g.

```
<input id="file-upload" type="file" accept="image/*" name="file-upload" />
```

Comment: `<input id="file-upload" type="file" accept="image/*" name="file-upload" capture="filesystem" />`

it still show "Camera snap" feature